# Text encoding difference by copy/paste or field typing

Tags: bluetooth, character-encoding

Here's the context: I'm developping a javascript webapp that can connect to a bluetooth device using chrome bluetooth feature. In the app settings, users can set up a WiFi connection through a form that will send a request to the device through BT connection.

I had yesterday some issues with the connection setup and I didn't figure out why because I could see in the logs that the sent password was correct, then I decided to fill out the password field by typing it instead of copy/pasting... the connection worked again.
**NOTE:** the WIFI password contains special characters.

After debugging what was going on on the device I figured out that the device firmware truncates the password when it is copy/pasted, which does not happen when the user types the password.

Here's an example password string I tested with:
Using copy/paste I sent: `nAC%o3HTpcP4I13S` and the device firmware received: `n%34I13S`.

Thus my question, what is the difference between a copy/paste and a direct input? I believe it's because of encoding but I can't name this problem. Anybody knows the best practices for such case?